# Selective Removal of Sodium Acetate

Tags: aqueous-solution, extraction, drugs

I am currently working on an extraction and synthesis of sodium salicyate from acetylsalicylic acid and sodium hydroxide. After doing a liquid-liquid extraction from DCM, using a sodium hydroxide solution, I am left with a solution containing sodium salicyate and sodium acetate. I need a way to remove the acetate while leaving the salicyate alone. Thank you!

Comment: Considering limited solubility of [salicylic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicylic_acid) in water and good solubility in some less polar solvents, I would try acidification and either crystallization at low temperature, either extraction. Probably the former.

Comment: Be sure that hydrolysis is complete (e.g., TLC with a lane of your starting material, a lane with your raw (but quenched) product, and a lane for co-spotting).  When then performing a back-extraction to yield salicylic acid, don't forget the addition of acid or a good amount will remain in the aqueous phase.  You go for the sodium salt *after* its acid was isolated.